# Inserting a resultset into jtable directly

Tags: java, jdbc

If is there any way to insert a resultset into jtable directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad idea.

You shouldn't be passing anything from the `java.sql` package out of your persistence tier.

You can certainly iterate over a `ResultSet` and load the contents into your `DefaultTableModel`.  But I wouldn't recommend it.

Something like this:

```
public DefaultTableModel map(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
{
    DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

    ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        Object [] rowData = new Object[numberOfColumns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i)
        {
            rowData[i] = resultSet.getObject(i+1);
        }
        defaultTableModel.addRow(rowData);
    }

    return defaultTableModel;
}
```

Comment: In fairness to mehdi, I added the code soon after he posted the comment.  He didn't see the code until after he asked the question.

Comment: @duffymo If you wouldn't recommend iterating over the ResultSet, what would be a better idea?

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't pass the ResultSet out of the persistence tier.  Load it into the DefaultTableModel, as shown.  What part of that isn't clear?